# Setting href attribute dynamically using js

Tags: javascript

I am able to set href properly like this:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute('href','doWork()');
```

However, I am clueless as to how do I do this when function needs a parameter:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute('href','doWork(money)';

#Using it like this, the url is doWork(money), but I need doWork(1), doWork(2)...
#I used a for loop, but doWork(i), when used with '' gives 'doWork(i)'.

#I have function doWork(money), with values of money ranging from 1 to 10.
```

How could I do that?

I have already tried this as per the links...mine is duplicate of.

```
for(var i=1; i<=10;i++){

 var link = 'doWork(i)'   #Sets link = doWork(i)
 var link = doWork(i);    #Nothing happens here

 a.setAttribute('href','doWork(i)';
```

Comment: Where does the `money` variable come from?  Couldn't you just call a function that retrieves that value?

Comment: @Marc: Sir, please see edits, the last block. My doWork(money) function needs values to operate, that's why I am sending values- money.

Comment: `var link = 'doWork('+ i + ');'; a.setAttribute('href',link);`  Can be done a little more cleanly with template strings, but I couldn't get the stackoverflow markup to escape backticks.

Comment: @Marc: Very nice, thanks a lot Sir. String concatenation it is, works nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this.

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute('href',`doWork(${money})`);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that works. But, why have you been downvoted, is it a bad way to use it like that?

Comment: @ksalf I think just because it was answered already.

Comment: No problem, I accepted the answer, however, the low rep that I am with, I just couldn't upvote. It would be very nice, if you explain it a bit, if you have time to do so. Thanks a lot !

Comment: if you want to use variables inside string , you need to wrap your string like this  `this is string ${yourVariable}`